# Must we reference copy-righted schemas (pictures)?

Tags: discussion

When we include schemas (photos) in our posts: **MUST** we include the resource/reference from where we took it?

Logically, we should, but I ask about the MUST. Are SE websites obeying to copy right laws?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the license under which the source permits use of its contents on third-party sites, but yes, source permitting, it's a good practice to always attribute with name and a link to the source.

Note that many sources don't permit direct sharing of their contents on other sites at all, so do check their ToS / copyright before doing that. SE stuff handles any copyright violation complaints on our behalf, but they might get mightily pissed, understandably so, if one single contributor causes them too many headaches and they subsequently have to remove those contents by themselves.

And frequent plagiarism, without following up on comments requesting attribution of sources (and clearly marking extracted texts with blockquote where applicable) can, and likely will, lead to suspension.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about SE, it's about the creator of the work. They control the copyright. Best practice is to always "cite your sources".